# iMAC Slow. %CPU -> 103,3 and Idle at 84%

Tags: macos, performance, cpu

Can you help me to understand why my iMAC is slow?
[image]

Open Xcode or Android studio take time, but idle time is always higher than 80%..

Comment: It looks like Google Backup-and-Sync is running wild. Perhaps you could uninstall it?

Comment: Well, this is why I upload the picture. I want to understand WHY the idle is at 80% if Google backup is taking 103%... I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges. In the small box at the bottom of your picture it says

```
System:           3,71 %
User:            11,65 %
Idle:            84,64 %
```

Sum those up and you get 100% - so it appears that User processes on your system are only consuming about 12% of the available CPU time, or about 1/8th of the CPU time available.

However, we also see that `Backup and sync from Google` is consuming 103,2%. How do we square this with the other numbers? Your computer has multiple cores (execution units), and the numbers shown on the individual process lines are core percentages, not total for the system. So the 49 separate threads launched by `Backup and sync from Google` are, in total, consuming 103,2% of a single core. This is about 12% of the total available CPU time, or about 1/8th (from the User time total), leading me to think that your computer has an 8-core CPU in it.